# Modifying or creating new result source on SharePoint 365 online

Tags: search, search-results, result-source, content-source

I have a department sharepoint site and I created a specific search results page to allow for custom filters to populate on the left panel.  I am having an issue, however, where search results are populating from other department sites and I want to restrict results to only content from my department's SharePoint.  I have been prompted to modify a "result source" but I'm not sure how to create a new result source that points only to my department site content.  Can someone advise how this should be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To create a result source you need to be a site collection admin (or a tenant admin).  The instructions are provided by microsoft at the following url: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-result-sources-fd8d6ac6-c5d0-454d-80a9-51580902b25d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

There are also other ways to attain the same result, with a Content Search Web Part.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a result source is much cleaner approach, another way would be to add the following filter

```
Path={Site.URL}
```

to the query builder of the Search Results web part on your search results page.